# Propagational delay in circuits

Tags: circuit, vlsi, asic

which is better for accurate proportional delay: spice simulation method or calculation using elmores delay (RC delay modeling)

Comment: This question is off-topic on Stack Overflow, but may have a chance on [Electronics SE](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/).

Answer (score 1):

Spice simulation is more accurate than elmore delay modelling. This is mentioned in the book CMOS VLSI Design by Weste Harris on page 93, Section 2.6

> Blindly trusting one’s models
>   Models should be viewed as only approximations to reality, not reality itself, and used within
>   their limitations. In particular, simple models like the Shockley or RC models aren’t even close
>   to accurate fits for the I-V characteristics of a modern transistor. They are valuable for the
>   insight they give on trends (i.e., making a transistor wider increases its gate capacitance and
>   decreases its ON resistance), not for the absolute values they predict. Cutting-edge projects
>   often target processes that are still under development, so these models should only be
>   viewed as speculative. Finally, processes may not be fully characterized over all operating regimes;
>   for example, don’t assume that your models are accurate in the subthreshold region
>   unless your vendor tells you so. Having said this, modern SPICE models do an extremely good
>   job of predicting performance well into the GHz range for well-characterized processes and
>   models when using proper design practices (such as accounting for temperature, voltage, and
>   process variation).